TextFormField with same height of text adjacent "cells" of Text causes cursor vertical position strange behavior
I'm trying to create a layout in which TextFormField's have the same height as adjacent "cells" of Text using a SizedBox with a given height. However, the result is that the cursor moves up in vertical direction in a strange way depending on fontsize of the TextFormField. See print and the snippet below (or just copy paste to dartpad).

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = ScrollController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Scrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _controller,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 400,
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text('test'),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: DecoratedBox(
                                      child: Text(
                                        '10',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      autofocus: true,
                                      cursorHeight: 20,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      ),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: '?',
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                          ),
                                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(0),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: DecoratedBox(
                                      child: Text(
                                        '10',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      autofocus: true,
                                      cursorHeight: 20,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      ),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: '?',
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                          ),
                                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(0),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            OutlinedButton(
                              child: Text('Try'),
                              onPressed:
                                  () {}, //submit form when both numbers are filled
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



I saw on this answer that there is a property contentPadding for inputDecoration of the TextFormField, and I could use it as a "hack" to move the cursor back to the center adding padding to the top, but this will break as soon as font changes and etc.
So, what could a robust solution be?
